# How do i change column layout in bootstrap 4 based on Odd / Even childs

Tags: wordpress, layout, bootstrap-4, multiple-columns

I'm a Dutch ICT student asking for help,
I know how to change the column layout based on the width of the screen but I want to change the layout for odd and even objects.

I want to accomplish the following:

[image: What I want]

So I want my layout to be:

```
col[7]col[5]
col[5]col[7]
col[7]col[5]
col[5]col[7]
```

I can't do this manually because I linked it with WordPress, so when I post a new item I want it to automatically get the right column layout.

My code looks like this:

[image: this]

Comment: Please, always transcribe your code using the `{ }` code button. Ideally if possible, even the `<>` js fiddle button that would allow us to test and compile in real time. For a lot of us our time is valuable here and transcribing code from a picture can be a chore

Answer (score 3):

Please try below solution hope this work for you.

With the using Modulo, for that, you need to declare `$i=0;` variable in above while loop also set `$i++;` at the bottom for increment `$i` value.

Please use below code.

```
<?php 
$i=0;
while( $qry->have_posts() ): $qry->the_post();
if ($i % 2 == 0)
{
  echo '<div class="col-md-7">7</div>';
  echo '<div class="col-md-5">5</div>';
} 
else 
{
  echo '<div class="col-md-5">5</div>';
  echo '<div class="col-md-7">7</div>';
}
$i++;
?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```